# Change animation of material-ui dialog show

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to change show animation of dialog in material-ui for react using css? I'm not advanced in css but I know that there exists something like transtion and transform.

Comment: It's possible, just deactivate the dafault animation and add your custom. You can add basic animation via jQuery/javascript or using CSS `transform` and `transition`, that's right.

Answer (score 13):

**12/2021 UPDATE:**

The answer below was written for an early release of material-ui v1 and is ancient history.  With material-ui version 5, the concept is basically the same and the current [Dialog Demo](https://mui.com/components/dialogs/#transitions) shows how this can be accomplished.

Import the transition you want, but you need to use `React.forwardRef` because the transition expects to receive a `ref` (more on that in the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)):

```
import Slide from '@mui/material/Slide';

const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
  return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});
```

Then:

```
 <Dialog
   open={open}
   TransitionComponent={Transition}
   keepMounted
   onClose={handleClose}
   aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
 >
```

---

**Original Material-UI V1 Answer:**

The Dialog component exposes a transition prop that can be used to override the default.  There is an example in the [Dialog demo](https://v1.mui.com/demos/dialogs/#alerts) (labeled *Slide in Alert Dialog*) that uses their provided Slide transition:

```
import Slide from 'material-ui/transitions/Slide';
```

Then:

```
<Dialog open={this.state.open} transition={Slide} onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}>
```

Here are the transition components they provide:

- [Collapse](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/api/collapse/)
- [Fade](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/api/fade/)
- [Grow](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/api/grow/)
- [Slide](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/api/slide/)

If none of these serve your purpose, you can use them as a starting point for creating your own Transition component.